# What are the IP addresses in my iptables chain FORWARD settings in a Dokku/docker setup?

Tags: firewall, iptables, postgresql, docker

I've been playing around with Dokku on DigitalOcean (following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application) guide) and I'm trying to understand current firewall settings.

So here's my setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Dokku

  - Docker (as part of Dokku)
  - PostgreSQL within my Dokku container (using [dokku-postgresql-plugin](https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-postgresql-plugin))
- fail2ban (I installed this myself, wasn't part of the Dokku template)

What I can't wrap my mind around are the Chain FORWARD settings - specifically the IP addresses next to `tcp dpt:5000` and `tcp dpt:postgresql`.

```
me:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             XXX.17.0.50          tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             XXX.17.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
me:~$
```

I'd guess that the `XXX.17.0.Y` IP addresses are originating within my Docker container - is that a fair guess? Assuming that's the case, they probably are not accessible to the outside world, correct?

What I'm trying to ultimately do is get reasonable secure firewall settings in place; e.g., lock down all input except for SSH, HTTP & HTTPS. I just want to make sure I understand the existing settings before I continue.

Comment: If XXX isn't 10 or 127, I think they may be accessible to the outside world.

Comment: @muru, interesting - they are *not* 10 or 127. I can ping those IPs , but the requests just time out. So it seems like they originate within my Docker container - I'm assuming I could restrict them from being accessible to the outside world in the Chain OUTPUT section? It's just not clear to me how I'd do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lock down all you or shut down all ports 
 
& to only use ssh & http & https just open thier ports

flush to be confused that u know whats already defined

```
$ iptables -F
```

then drop all

```
$ iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

#### 1st for ssh  port :

IPTABLES to pop open port 22

```
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

#### 2nd for http & https port :

allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere.
"default ports for websites" / http 80, https 443.

```
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

#### Finally close all other traffics:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

#### All

```
$ iptables -F
$ -P INPUT DROP
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

#### OR

```
$ iptables -F
$ iptables -P INPUT DROP
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
$ iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```